# Windows XP USB driver

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I am facing a problem with a Windows XP SP3 (Home Edition) and USB devices.

When I connect a USB Stick device, it is recognized but the Hardware Wizard pops up and I cannot find any drivers.

The USB sticks are working fine to other PCs.

Any solution?

Comment: reinstall Windows ^^

Answer (score 0):

Check your **`C:\Windows\Inf directory`** and check for make sure that **usbstor.inf** and **usbstor.pnf** are both there.

If they aren't there, copy them from a working installation or from your Windows media.

Comment: What should he do if one or both of those files is missing?